# Why is Maven target directory called so?

Tags: maven, build, naming-conventions

In Maven target directory is where all the output of a build is held. This convention is also followed in many others build systems (like sbt, scala build tool).

The question that arises is "Why is the target directory called so?". Is it because this directory is the 'target' of the build process or what?

Comment: Yes, it is where the build will create all its artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that a lot of different things happen in the target directory, not just building.  For example, if you do mvn jetty:run it runs a jetty web server using the classes in target, and the files in your maven project.

Comment: Well, the fact that a lot of things take place in this directory does not make `target` the #1 choice for its name. I think there should be a more deep explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think target has been used as the destiniation folder of various creative actions in computer science for quite some time.  The documentation of many linux commands make use of the term.  Since most of the build is doing copying a file or creating a folder, it makes sense that it's nomenclature would resemble these commands.

From the mv info page:

```
The mv command is used to rename and move files and directories. Its general syntax is:

mv [options] argument(s)

The arguments are names of files and directories. If two file names are provided as arguments, mv renames the first as the second. If a list of arguments is provided and the final argument in the sequence is the name of an existing directory, mv moves all of the other items into that directory. If the final argument is not an existing directory and more than two arguments are provided, an error message is returned.

mv's syntax can also be expressed in a less general form as:

mv [options] source target

If the target file is located in the same directory as the source file, then the source file can only be renamed. If both are in different directories, then the source file is moved to the directory named in the target argument, in which it can keep its original name or be assigned a new name. If the target is a directory, then the source file or directory is moved into that directory and retains its original name.
```

Comment: I like this explanation. So, `target` carried on from older times, since now even simple builds do far more than copying files around.

Comment: But even complicated build tasks could be seen as little more than creating, moving and copying files.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Thanks for the answer!